# MS Graph API frequently/excessively triggering the client app against Active Directory User changes

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, integration, publish-subscribe, change-notification

**Background:**

I wanted to receive notifications in a *Logic App* for *Azure Active Directory* Users' changes. I created a subscription to AD User changes using *Microsoft Graph*'s REST API:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions

{
    "changeType": "updated",
    "notificationUrl": "https://mylogicapp.com",
    "resource": "/users",
    "expirationDateTime": "2021-11-11T11:00:00.0000000Z",
    "clientState": "SecretClientState"
}
```

I received `201 Created` HTTP response code and began receiving the notifications in the application. (See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks)).

**Issue:**
I am receiving a lot more than the expected notifications, very frequently. I just want to receive notifications scoped to AD User resource type and not any child resource type. What could be the issue behind that abundant User changes' notifications? Did I do anything wrong or missed anything while setting the scope in *Subscription Creation* request?

[image]

Comment: Hope you have gone through [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/msgraph-changenotifications-trackchanges/) module too.

Comment: Yes, I did. But it didn't help. However, thanks.